# ReflectionException Class does not exist psr-4

Tags: php, laravel, psr-4

I'm fairly new to laravel and have encountered a problem with the psr-4 autoloading in my application.

My folder structure:

```
-app
 -config
  -controllers
   -UsersController
  -Mynamespace
   -User.php
```

My composer.json file:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
      "Mynamespace\\": "app/Mynamespace"
    }
```

Then I ran:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

My User model:

```
<?php namespace Mynamespace;

use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;
use Eloquent;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {
...
```

My vendor/composer/autoload-psr4.php:

```
...
return array(
    'Monolog\\' => array($vendorDir . '/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog'),
    'Mynamespace\\' => array($baseDir . '/app/Mynamespace'),
);
```

Changed my config/auth.php to:

```
'model' => 'Mynamespace\User',
```

I keep getting a ReflectionException Class User does not exist error. Please help!

Comment: Have you changed `model` in [`app/config/auth.php`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/config/auth.php#L31) to `Mynamespace\User`?

Comment: Yes to  'model' => 'Mynamespace/User',

Comment: Your user model is stored in a file named `User.php`, right? I ask because you referred to it as your UsersController.

Comment: Right! sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

You reflection exception

> Class User does not exist error

is complaining about not being able to find a class named `User`.  I don't see a class named `User` defined anywhere in the above code.  I see a class named `Mynamespace\User`, but I don't see a global class named user.

Knowing the context that you're seeing this exception in would help, but my guess is something told Laravel to instantiate a global `User` object (dependency injected type hints? Instantiating an object through `app()->make`? Directly Instantiating an object?).  Without that context it's not likely anyone will be able to track this down for you.